# I am getting a " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined "

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to retrieve a json from another microservice (local) using a different port. I am not sure if the issue is with my config or the microservice. When I hit the url I do get the json to display on the page.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/*****', { responseType: 'json' }).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

`*****` = page where to retrieve the json

I am expecting a json however I get an error message.

Comment: Can you show how `http` is injected into your service?

Comment: like this : import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue I have found my mistake. The controller on the other micro service was missing @CrossOrigin just before the RequestMapping. that fixed my error on the front end where the call was being made.

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should've something like this:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getData(): Observable<any> {
    const apiURL = `http://localhost:8081/*****`;
    const opts = {
       responseType: 'json'
    };

   return this.httpClient.post(apiURL, opts);
  }
}
```

**From your component:**

```
import { TestService} from '..test.service';

export class TestClass {

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  getInfo() {
   this.testService.getData().subscribe(data => {
     console.log('***TEST***' + data);
   }); 
  }
 }
```

Comment: How would I go if i want to call getData from my component?

Comment: Updated my answer